# How to print only certain columns from datframe in python after searching for a particular character in the values inside a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

example dataframe df:

```
Date      msft_close msft_high  signal
01-01-20    350         358      buy
02-01-20    370         377      sell
03-01-20    365         370      NaN
04-01-20    368         371      buy
```

```
df[df["signal"].astype(str).str.contains("buy")]
```

prints:

```
    Date      msft_close msft_high  signal
    01-01-20    350         358      buy
    04-01-20    368         371      buy
```

But i just want column msft_close only. How can i select to print the msft_close only after checking whether the signal column has buy ?
My target Output is :

```
    Date      msft_close 
    01-01-20    350      
    04-01-20    368
```

Comment: ```df.loc[df.signal.eq("buy"), ['Date','msft_close']]``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code instead-

```py
df[df["signal"].astype(str).str.contains("buy")]["msft_close"]
```

Which returns the `msft_close` column after the filter.

> Note: I assume the `Date` column is the index.